# cut off text if it doesn't fit in the Textview widget in Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a `TextView` and let's say for example I set it's width to 100dp.  If the text value is too long, it automatically tries to make a new line.

I DON'T want to do that.  I want to just show "..." at the end of the text so the user know there is more to this text.  When the user clicks on it, they will be able to all the text.

How can I limit it so the text doesn't go to the next line and always stays with the TextView's fixed size?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use a small set of attributes here, in order to make it compatible to many devices:

```
<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/my_text" 
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="text"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:lines="1"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:ellipsize="end" />
```

So basically `singleLine`. `lines` and `maxLines`.

Comment: singleline deprecated?

Comment: Not yet: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following `android:singleLine="true"`